# IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF - How to turn it ON?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a deleted file archive database that stores the ID of the file that was deleted,  I want the admin to be able to restore the file (as well as the same ID for linking files).  I do not want to take identity_insert off the entire table, as the increment by one works great.  In my insert to `TBL_Content` store procedure I have something like this

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[spInsertDeletedIntoTBLContent]
@ContentID int, 
...insert command...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content OFF
```

But I keep getting the same error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'TBL_Content' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Any help?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Should you instead be setting the identity insert to on within the stored procedure?  It looks like you're setting it to on only when changing the stored procedure, not when actually calling it.  Try:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spInsertDeletedIntoTBLContent]
@ContentID int, 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON

...insert command...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 29):

I believe it needs to be done in a single query batch.  Basically, the GO statements are breaking your commands into multiple batches and that is causing the issue.  Change it to this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON
/* GO */

...insert command...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content OFF
GO
```

Comment: You right. This is the point! The next command batch for insert should start with SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON; command again.

Answer (score 18):

Shouldn't you be setting identity_Insert ON, inserting the records and then turning it back off?

Like this:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[spInsertDeletedIntoTBLContent]
@ContentID int, 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON
...insert command...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content OFF
```

Answer (score 16):

**Reminder**

***SQL Server only allows one table to have IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.***

This does not work:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableA ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB ON
... INSERT ON TableA ...
... INSERT ON TableB ...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableA OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB OFF
```

Instead:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableA ON
... INSERT ON TableA ...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableA OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB ON
... INSERT ON TableB ...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB OFF
```

Comment: Very important piece of info I wish I knew earlier

Answer (score 8):

Add this line above you Query

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON
```

Answer (score 7):

The Reference:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

My table is named `Genre` with the 3 columns of `Id`, `Name` and `SortOrder`

The code that I used is as:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Genre ON

INSERT INTO Genre(Id, Name, SortOrder)VALUES (12,'Moody Blues', 20)
```

Answer (score 7):

Add set off also

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT Genre ON

    INSERT INTO Genre(Id, Name, SortOrder)VALUES (12,'Moody Blues', 20) 

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Genre  OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

I had two different tables and for the first one insert works fine but for the second one throws this exception regarding Identity Insert.
The issue was that the **table had a field(int) as a forgery key which wasn't populated**.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31212513)