# How to set Insert_Identity to on while post data using web API

Tags: post, webapi

I am getting error while posting data from web API.

> ExceptionMessage=Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
> table 'Tbl_Menu' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Can anyone please tell how to resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF - How to turn it ON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112579/identity-insert-is-set-to-off-how-to-turn-it-on)

Answer (score 0):

I Got Answer from my senior.

just change **WebApiConfig** File

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/**{action}**/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and use url for post data

```
http://localhost:14795/api/Guest/PostTbl_Menu
```